# Tzafnat Panei’ach

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, brit-milah, abraham

I’m looking for some help with Tzafnat Panei’ach’s commentary to Genesis 17:23 (pages [137](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21163&st=&pgnum=137&hilite=)-[138](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21163&st=&pgnum=138&hilite=) of [this PDF](https://hebrewbooks.org/21163)). Specifically:

- The author queries whether Abraham circumcised himself before his household, or vice versa. What is his answer to this and how does he reach this conclusion?

Then I’m following it for a bit until…

- The second half of the commentary relates to the haftarah (Isaiah). I don’t follow this at all, especially all the hammer stuff related to Masechet Shabbat. Can anyone assist?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the answer is that although Avraham circumcised himself before he circumcised his household members, nevertheless  being that Avraham’s Geirus wasn’t yet completed at the time that he circumcised them, being that we don’t find anywhere that he immersed himself, therefore his own circumcision only took affect once the circumcision of his household members was performed by him, which, according to the Rogachover, is considered the “final blow” which makes it a complete conversion - even without immersion - being that the conversion can be completed by performing a Mitzvah that is done only by a Jew

The analogy from the “hammer’s blow” is that just as Avraham’s circumcision took affect through the act of circumcising his household members, we find something similar to the Gemara, regarding Shabbos, that by banging a hammer against against a tree stump is considered “fixing” the hammer, being that it becomes more smooth by doing so

Comment: Classic Rogachover!

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Just to clarify: (1) is it simply an assumption that he didn’t immerse? (2) Is the extended hammer stuff really just that metaphor? 

Comment: @Zarka on your second point -- no hammers involved in circumcision! Someone with a solid Talmudic background would know that "striking with a hammer" is a rabbinic way of saying "putting the finishing touches on a job." (It's the last of the 39 categories of creative labor vis-a-vis Shabbos.)

Answer (score 2):

There are several details in what the Rogatchover is pointing out that are not so simple.

He emphasizes that unlike Yitzchok whose circumcision was for the mitzvah of Milah of a Yisrael, Avraham's circumcision was for conversion.

This is indicated because Avraham performed his circumcision at dawn, in contrast to Yitzchok's circumscision being performed after sunrise.

He then points out that there appears to be a conflict in the text of the Torah as to who was circumcised first, Avraham or *Yishmael and those from Avraham's household* (meaning those Avraham acquired as servants/slaves and those offspring born to those servants).

But in the final version of Tzaphnat Paneach, he discusses in regard to circumcision and immersion that even though immersion in the mikvah is the completion of the conversion process, one becomes a convert retroactively (*meaning back to when the cicumcision was actually performed*). Further on, he explains that a non-Jew cannot circumcise a Jew, even though Avraham circumcised the members of his household prior to immersion and after his milah.

The Rogatchaver then brings a concept from Rambam to resolve the issue from Hilchot Issurei Bi'ah, Chapter 13:9, that one who conducts themselves completely according to Jewish practice has a presumption of being a *Righteous Convert*. (In this context, it is worth noting that the Patriachs and Matriachs kept all the commandments even before they were given at Sinai.)

That this would apply to Avraham when he assisted the members of his household with their circumcisions. By *assisting* them, which is in general a Jewish practice, Avraham completed his conversion (*the so called **striking of the final hammer blow***) and he brings Isaiah 41:6 as proof of this which says:

> **אִ֥ישׁ אֶת־רֵעֵ֖הוּ יַעְזֹ֑רוּ** וּלְאָחִ֖יו יֹאמַ֥ר חֲזָֽק׃

He then adds an additional, seemingly unnecessary, detail here that this pertains to a female convert who conducts herself according to Jewish practice, like immersing in a mikvah following her period or to a man who immerses  following nocturnal emission.

And in this context, the Rogatchover seems to be pointing to at least the possibility that Avraham was circumcised by his wife, Sarah, like is understood from Bereshit 2:18 which also says concerning the creation of the wife of Adam:

> וַיֹּ֙אמֶר֙ יְהוָ֣ה אֱלֹהִ֔ים לֹא־ט֛וֹב הֱי֥וֹת הָֽאָדָ֖ם לְבַדּ֑וֹ **אֶֽעֱשֶׂהּ־לּ֥וֹ עֵ֖זֶר כְּנֶגְדּֽוֹ**׃

That ones wife is also referred to as ones *assistant* and thus, Sarah had a presumption of being a Righteous Convert because like her husband, she too kept all the commandments before they were given including Taharat HaMishpacha.

And like her, the circumcisions performed by Avraham on the members of his household were valid because he followed Jewish practice before the commandments were given and was presumed a Righteous Convert immediately upon himself being circumcised.

And this same paradigm also seems to be the basis of the action of Moshe's wife, Tzipporah like is found in Shemot 4:25-26 which says:

> וַתִּקַּ֨ח צִפֹּרָ֜ה צֹ֗ר וַתִּכְרֹת֙ אֶת־עׇרְלַ֣ת בְּנָ֔הּ וַתַּגַּ֖ע לְרַגְלָ֑יו וַתֹּ֕אמֶר כִּ֧י חֲתַן־דָּמִ֛ים אַתָּ֖ה לִֽי׃
> וַיִּ֖רֶף מִמֶּ֑נּוּ אָ֚ז אָֽמְרָ֔ה חֲתַ֥ן דָּמִ֖ים לַמּוּלֹֽת׃

Comment: Thank you for this but I can’t see any reference to the “additional, seemingly unnecessary, detail” in the version of the commentary  linked in my question? Ie no references to a woman immersing for niddah or a man for an emission. Is there another version?

Comment: @Zarka See note 123 on page 137 from your link.

Comment: Ah. But those notes aren’t by the Rogatchover?

Comment: @Zarka But they are bringing what the Rogatchover cites in his text. Similarly, when learning a ma’amar by the Lubavitcher Rebbe, he cites many things which are actually listed in the notes. (The Rebbe is reported to have received semicha from the Rogatchover)  When learning a discourse, it is more appropriate to actually look up the citations and learn the specific language being cited so as to comprehend properly what is taught in the main text in brevity. This is often called “learning inside”. Doing so also makes clear the living chain of transmission that is עץ חיים. Blessings only.

Comment: @Zarka This is the essence of the introductory letter from Rabbi Menachem Kasher, z”l, the head of Machon Tzafnat Pa’aneach and author of Torah Shleimah. The majority of the notes were actually made by the Rogatchover’s close students.